# Deploy or Run Functions Locally (HTTP functions + Realtime Database functions )

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I run HTTP functions and Realtime Database functions simultaneously

I see in the documentation here : [Run functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_realtime_database_functions) how to run HTTP functions by the following command : `firebase serve` and for the Realtime Database functions : `firebase functions:shell` but it doesn't work for me.

And also when I deployed my functions with command `firebase deploy --only functions` it only deploy my HTTP function .

What is wrong with my approach ?

structure:

```
/functions
|--index.js
|--saveDetectedBeacons.js
|--generatePresence.js
|--package.json
```

index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const saveDetectedBeaconsFunc = require('./saveDetectedBeacons');
const generatePresenceFunc = require('./generatePresence');
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://exampleDb.firebase.com"
});
const db = admin.database();
exports.saveDetectedBeaconsApi = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    saveDetectedBeaconsFunc.handler(request,response,db)
});
exports.generatePresenceApi = functions.database.ref('/reports').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    generatePresenceFunc.handler(snapshot, context, db)
});
```

saveDetectedBeacons.js:

```
exports.handler = function (request, response, db) {
    // do something 
};
```

generatePresence.js

```
exports.handler = function (snapshot, context, db) {
     // do something 
};
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "run all my functions".  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I mean run the HTTP functions and Realtime Database functions because when I use command ( firebase serve ) it only run the HTTP functions not the both

Comment: also when I deployed the functions it deploy only the HTTP, is there any thing wrong in my project structure or my code ?